# Apparent inconsistency in iterator requirements

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator

I am implementing some type-traits/concept classes to check that a type passed to a generic function satisfies the compile-time requirements for iterator types (as defined in the standard, starting from 24.2.2).

The problem is that a basic iterator requirement (Table 106) is that the type of `*r` (where `r` is a reference to an iterator of type `T`) is `std::iterator_traits<T>::reference`. However, if we consider an output iterator such as `std::ostream_iterator`,

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/ostream_iterator

we can see how in this case the `reference` type is `void`, whereas the `operator*()` of the iterator type returns `std::ostream_iterator &`.

Clearly, I am misunderstanding something here, but I can't see what? Does it have anything to do with the fact that output iterators can be dereferenced only on the left side of an assignment?

EDIT: I would like to clarify that my question is about the inconsistency between the reference type and the type resulting from calling `operator*()` on `std::ostream_iterator` (and a bunch of other output iterators in the standard library).

Answer (score 2):

24.2.1 [iterator.requirements.general]/11

> In the following sections, a and b denote values of type X or const X,
>   difference_type and reference refer to the types
>   iterator_traits::difference_type and 
>   iterator_traits::reference, respectively

`reference` is not `allocator_traits<T>::reference`, but `iterator_traits<T>::reference`.

Now, in the standard `std::ostream_iterator<T>` is defined as:

```
class ostream_iterator:
                   public iterator<output_iterator_tag, void, void, void, void> {
```

The last argument to the `std::iterator` template is the *reference type*, which means that `iterator_traits<T>::reference` is required to be `void` for `std::ostream_iterator<T>`.

At the same time, 24.2.1/1 requires:

> [...] All output iterators support the expression *i = o where o is a value of some type that is in the set of types that are writable to the particular iterator type of i. [...]

This might be the part that you are missing that guarantees that the assignment works. I imagine that the `reference` being `void` somehow represents that you cannot *read* out of this, but I guess it could be improved.

Comment: Well `*r` is *not* of type `reference` (not `void`) for output iterators, so this requirement is not satisfied (if it is a requirement).

Comment: Right, but the confusing part is that an output iterator is supposed to be a refinement of the iterator concept, for which the reference cannot be void (as it must be the type of ``*r`` according to the common iterator requirements). EDIT: what @dyp says.

Comment: @dyp: There is a contradiction on those two requirements. If the type of `*i` is `void` it cannot be assigned from the appropriate type, if it can be assigned then it cannot be `void`. Maybe a DR... it could be required that `reference` is `std::ostream_iterator<T>&`...

Comment: @bluescarni: Input and Output iterators are special beasts. All others are related, but not these two. The requirements might be wrong, but assuming that Input and Output iterators are *iterators* in the same way than Forward, Bidirectional, Random... that is going to get you into trouble :)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas yes they look like pretty different beasts :) The way the standard is worded seemed to imply some sort of OOP hierarchy in the iterator types (a-la Output iterator is-a Base iterator), but maybe that is not the case.

Comment: @bluescarni: No, there is no OOP type of hierarchy. For example, both input and output iterators are single pass iterators. The definition of equality is, well, against any common sense definition of what equality should be for two values: `a == b` does not imply `++a == ++b` (this is contrary to value types, where if you start with two values being the same, and you apply the same operations, the result is that the two values hold the same *value* (i.e. still compare `==`).